# Copying multiple pages and clearing cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have 7 sheets in my excel file that I need to copy all at once. I have created a button to do this with the code shown below. However, I also want to be able to clear some of the cells when I copy the sheets. I have tried to modify the second set of code from a different workbook that was copying one page at a time and clearing cells but I can't seem to get it to work. The code does not need to search for the most recent week as the code shown below does, I just need it to copy my 7 sheets and clear cells G18:G37 on sheets 2 through 7. Thanks

'What i have right now.'

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Worksheets(Array("Coding Details", "Schedule A", "Schedule B", "Schedule C", "Schedule D", "Schedule E", "Schedule F")).Copy After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)

End Sub
```

'What i am using in my other workbook'

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim wrkSht As Worksheet
Dim lWkNum As Long
Dim lCurNum As Long
Dim sht_LastWeek As Worksheet
Dim sht_NewWeek As Worksheet

'Find previous week and set reference to it.
For Each wrkSht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If IsNumeric(Replace(wrkSht.Name, "Week ", "")) Then
        lCurNum = CLng(Replace(wrkSht.Name, "Week ", ""))
        If lCurNum > lWkNum Then lWkNum = lCurNum
    End If
Next wrkSht
Set sht_LastWeek = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Week " & lWkNum)

'Create new sheet, set reference to it and rename.
sht_LastWeek.Copy After:=Sheets(sht_LastWeek.Index)
Set sht_NewWeek = Sheets(sht_LastWeek.Index + 1)
sht_NewWeek.Name = "Week " & lCurNum + 1

'Clear the cells and relink formula to previous sheet.
With sht_NewWeek
    .Range("B40:J45,C18:I21,E26:F31").ClearContents
    .Cells.Replace What:="'Week " & lCurNum - 1 & "'!", _
                   Replacement:="'Week " & lCurNum & "'!", _
                   LookAt:=xlPart
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim n As Long, wb As Workbook

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    wb.Worksheets(Array("Coding Details", "Schedule A", "Schedule B", _
                    "Schedule C", "Schedule D", "Schedule E", "Schedule F")).Copy _
                    After:=wb.Worksheets(wb.Worksheets.Count)
    For n = 0 To 5
        wb.Worksheets(wb.Worksheet.Count - n).Range("G18:G37").ClearContents
    Next n


End Sub
```